# Changing the default indentation of etree.tostring in lxml

Tags: python, lxml, pretty-print

I have an XML document which I'm pretty-printing using `lxml.etree.tostring`

```
print etree.tostring(doc, pretty_print=True)
```

The default level of indentation is 2 spaces, and I'd like to change this to 4 spaces.  There isn't any argument for this in the `tostring` function; is there a way to do this easily with lxml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said in [this thread](http://codespeak.net/pipermail/lxml-dev/2009-February/004350.html), there is no real way to change the indent of the `lxml.etree.tostring` pretty-print.

But, you can:

- add a XSLT transform to change the indent
- add whitespace to the tree, with something like in the [cElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/element-lib.htm) library

code:

```
def indent(elem, level=0):
    i = "\n" + level*"  "
    if len(elem):
        if not elem.text or not elem.text.strip():
            elem.text = i + "  "
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = i
        for elem in elem:
            indent(elem, level+1)
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = i
    else:
        if level and (not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip()):
            elem.tail = i
```

Comment: The link to lxml-dev list archives from Feb 2009 is broken, it's at: https://mailman-mail5.webfaction.com/pipermail/lxml/20090208/012298.html . But anyway, kludging whitespace into actual tree elements seems nasty, haven't people asked for this as an enhance?

Comment: @smci: There is a built-in `indent()` function since lxml 4.5 (released 2020-01-29). See the answer from @kuch.

Answer (score 14):

Since version 4.5, [you can set indent size](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#serialisation) using `indent()` function.

```
etree.indent(root, space="    ")
print(etree.tostring(root))
```

Comment: Note that this sometimes behaves differently than the `pretty_print` option. Try to indent `<a><b>Some <c>mixed</c> <c>content</c>.</b></a>` to see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done, using XMLParser and indent. There is no need for pretty_print :

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = etree.parse('myfile.xml',parser) 
etree.indent(tree, space="    ")
tree.write('myfile.xml', encoding='UTF-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73007413/2823074). Changing the `space` value allows you to get any indent you want. It can be different amount of spaces or tab `"\t"` character(s).