# XML indentation set to 4 spaces

Tags: python, xml, lxml, indentation

I'm using the following code to indent, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086922/python-pretty-xml-printer-with-lxml):

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = etree.parse(filename, parser)
```

However, the original XML file is indented with 4 spaces and after using the code above it indents to 2 spaces. Any way to keep the 4 space indentation?

**ADDED**

I'm writing the tree like this:

```
xml = etree.parse("/path/to/the/xml/file")

with open("/file.xml", "wb") as f:
    f.write(etree.tostring(xml, pretty_print=True, encoding='utf8'))
```

followed by the `parse` and `tree` variables above.

Comment: Maybe I jumped the gun on this one ... How are you actually _writing_ the lxml tree?  All you're showing here is how you _read_ the tree.