# Python: Tag mismatch while copying nodes in xml using lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml, python-3.7

I am new to xml and was trying to copy a node. Though it copies the node, when i append it, the closing tags mismatch. Here is the xml that i am parsing.

```
<doc>
    <branch name="release01" hash="f200013e">
        <sub-branch name="subrelease01">
            xml,sgml
        </sub-branch>
    </branch>
</doc>
```

Here is the code that i am using to parse the xml:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
import copy

tree = ET.ElementTree(file="doc2.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

lst_nodes = tree.findall("branch")
ele = 0

while ele < len(lst_nodes):
    ref = lst_nodes[ele]
    if (lst_nodes[ele].attrib.get("name") == "release01"):
        count = 0
        while count < 1:
            copied = copy.deepcopy(ref)
            ref.append(copied)
            count=count+1
    ele+=1

ET.dump(root)
```

The output observed is:

```
<doc>
    <branch name="release01" hash="f200013e">
        <sub-branch name="subrelease01">
            xml,sgml
        </sub-branch>
    <branch name="release01" hash="f200013e">
        <sub-branch name="subrelease01">
            xml,sgml
        </sub-branch>
    </branch>
</branch>
</doc>
```

As you can see end tag of "branch" is mismatched. Can someone help me to identify the mistake that i am doing while copying or appending the node?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the output you are trying to produce is:

```
<doc>
    <branch name="release01" hash="f200013e">
        <sub-branch name="subrelease01">
            xml,sgml
        </sub-branch>
    </branch>
    <branch name="release01" hash="f200013e">
        <sub-branch name="subrelease01">
            xml,sgml
        </sub-branch>
    </branch>
</doc>
```

The mistake you are making is that you are appending your copy of `ref` to the elements which make up `ref` itself, and not placing your copy *after* `ref` (i.e. you want the copy to be a sibling of `ref` and not a child). To achieve the desired behaviour you need to append your copy of ref to the parent element of `ref` this can be achieved by using the `getparent()` method and then using `append()` or even more conveniently you can directly use Element's `addnext()` method.

i.e. replace `ref.append(copy)` with `ref.addnext(copy)`

[addnext API Reference](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#addnext)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked. But after the end tag of first branch, the new sibling starts in the same line instead of new line. Pretty_print didn't solve the problem. Any solution.

Comment: That's strange, dump seems to be for debugging purposes only according to the API reference. Does the same problem occur when printing the result of the tostring() method? (with pretty_print=True) and when writing tostring() to file?

Comment: Yes. I tried writing to a file using tostring() method. The result was same. No need new line was added at the start of new sibling.

Comment: Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9612463/5910149,
instantiate your tree object using a parser that removes blank spaces.

parser = ET.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = ET.ElementTree(file="doc2.xml", parser=parser)

Comment: An explanation for this behaviour is given in the lxml doucmentation: https://lxml.de/FAQ.html#why-doesn-t-the-pretty-print-option-reformat-my-xml-output