# Remove empty lines from XML file with LXML

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Let's have this in an XML file (`in.xml`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<a>
  <b>
    <c>abc</c>
  </b>
</a>
```

Now, I run this code to strip the tag `<b>` and write the result back in a file:

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('in.xml', parser=etree.XMLParser())
root = tree.getroot()
etree.strip_tags(root, 'b')
tree.write('out.xml', xml_declaration=True)
```

This output file (`out.xml`) looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
<a>
  
    <c>abc</c>
  
</a>
```

How can I remove the blank lines left by the stripped tag?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but when an xml is parsed is not treated as a text but every leaf as objects theirselves. When you do strip_tags, you delete the object itself, but not the descendants or tails. In fact, it will merge the descendants to the parent of the stripped tag.

Comment: This is it https://stackoverflow.com/a/9612463/2834978

Comment: You're right, `tree = etree.parse('in.xml', parser=etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True))
` works. I thought this would be treated at the time of writing and that any setting in the `parse` method would only apply when reading the file. Thanks!

Comment: @UnsignedFoo, you are correct.