# Python:LXML - How to add an element under a specific tag to an existing element tree

Tags: python, android, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I use the following codes to try to append the element under tag `resources`.

```
parser = Et.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False)
xml_tree = Et.parse(destination_xml_file_full_path, parser=parser)
xml_tree_root_element = xml_tree.getroot()

string_element = Et.Element('string')
string_element.set('name', string_id)
string_element.text = ''

xml_tree_root_element.append(string_element)

# Write the modified xml file.
xml_tree.write(destination_xml_file_full_path, encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=False, pretty_print=True)
```

Expected:

```
<resources>
    <string name="cbp_payment_successful">Payment Successful</string>
    ...
    <string name="string id"></string> // wanna to add this line of code

</resources>
```

Actual:

```
<resources>
    <string name="cbp_payment_successful">Payment Successful</string>
    ...

<string name="string id"></string> // wanna to add this line of code</resources>
```

I already know I can use Android Studio reformat to achieve that, but is there any better way to achieve it only using Python?

**Idea 1:**

find the resources tag and append an element under the tag, but is there any API for that?

**Idea 2:**

find the last string element, and get the root of the string element, and use insert

Comment: So this is about pretty-printing?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/749796/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/5086922/407651

Comment: @mzjn not sure, but anyway `pretty_print=True` does not work for it.

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9612463/407651

Comment: appending  `remove_blank_text ` into `xml_tree.write(destination_xml_file_full_path, encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=False, pretty_print=True)` will be runtime error. 

Do you know how to combine  `remove_blank_text` with the existing one?

@mzjn

Comment: Look closely at the linked answer again. `remove_blank_text=True` is a parameter on the `parser` object. It does not belong in the `write()` method.